# Need To Import Sub-Framework Header File for JNI in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, java-native-interface

The `JavaVM` framework contains a sub-framework, `JavaNativeFoundation` framework. This sub-framework contains a header file, `JNFRunLoop.h`, that I need.

According to Apple documentation:

```
#import <Framework_name/Header_filename.h>
```

> In both cases, Framework_name is the name of the framework and
>   Header_filename is the name of a header file in that framework  or in
>   one of its subframeworks.

`#import <JavaVM/JNFRunLoop.h>` does not work (JavaVM/JNFRunLoop.h file not found).

I tried adding the sub-framework headers to the header search path, and while this allows me to import it, it gives a compile-time error which is mentioned in the documentation:

> The umbrella header files and the subframework header files contain
>   preprocessor variables and checks to guard against the inclusion of
>   subframework header files.

I ultimately need to do this:

```
[JNFRunLoop performOnMainThreadWaiting:YES withBlock:block];
```

which won't work until I can import that header file. Any ideas?

Comment: I think JavaVM is deprecated framework you need to use oracle java framework.

Comment: Could you post links to the mentioned libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authors of the library have put that guard on purpose. Are you sure you are doing the right thing?

If the library allows modifications the right way would be to take it and adapt it to your needs.

If you need a quick and dirty way to call that method, you can try to declare it inside your ".m" file like so:

```
@interface JNFRunLoop
+ (void)performOnMainThreadWaiting:(BOOL)w withBlock:(void (^)(void))b;
@end
```

(it must match to how it is declared in JNFRunLoop.h in terms of name and parameter types)

After this declaration it becomes available for calling. Note that this won't work, if the library requires some special initialization steps, or if that function name is mangled in their binary or not present their.

Comment: Thanks. I get the same error when building as I do when adding it to the header search path or framework search path. That is: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_JNFRunLoop", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyClass.o

Comment: Oh to address your concern about doing the right thing. This framework is absolutely necessary. I also need to use JNF_COCOA_ENTER(env); and JNF_COCOA_EXIT(env); which is also part of that framework.

Comment: If you get "Undefined symbols" it means that you either forgot to link that framework with your app, or you did that, but that function itself is either mangled inside the binary or just not present. That's unfortunate.

If you need to use macros, then yes, you need to get a build of that framework that allows using it normally (i.e. not embedded into JavaVM, but separate).

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem with the building (linking that framework).